# Creating multiple line grid frames in QGIS Print Composer?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, print-composer

I've found an older map with a nice-looking grid frame.

[image]

How can I create this with the QGIS Print Composer (also programmatically with Python)? I didn't found anything to control the line style of the grid frame.

*Update

There is the possibility to duplicate the grid frame style of the topographic map (see the comment to LaughUs answer). Logically you can't use "Move item content" with another map and a rectangle on top. You have to uncheck these two elements first to move within your map and then you have to adapt the extents.

I'm wondering why there is an option to change the line style of the grid and not for the frame. Until now I've never used a special line style for the grid lines (multiple lines, etc.) for my GIS work.

Answer (score 5):

I've created the result with QGIS 2.18.13 and you will need to add four grids to your map:

**1. Grid:** will hold the marks, the annotations and you will set the intervals here. Values I used: grid type "Cross", intervals x + y each 500m cross width 3,0 mm The grid Frane style is "interior ticks and size is 2,0 mm. As Format for the coordinates is used a Custom expression with  `to_int(@grid_number)`. And the Vertical ascending for drawing.

**2. Grid:** Grid type "Cross" and made the crosses transparent by changing the line style. The grid frame style is "line Border" with 0,3 mm thickness and in my example a dark gray ( you can use black)

**3. Grid:** grid type cross and the crosses transparent by changing the line style. The grid frame style is "line Border" with 0,6 mm thickness and in my example white colour.

**4: Grid:** grid type cross and the crosses transparent by changing the line style: The grid frame style is "line Border" with 1 mm thickness and in my example black colour.

The result is this image.

[image: An example of a frame]
To make it a perfect fit. You will need to play around with the numbers I think but the general looks can be duplicated.

Comment: With your approach I can nearly duplicate the look of the old map. I added a 5th grid to set exterior ticks to get the hole line from the outermost part to the innermost part of the grid frame. To get the perfect duplicate you have to set an offset value to the "inner" frame line to move it a bit outwards. But there is no option for this in the item properties.

Comment: @Stefan I see what you mean but I out of ideas for that. It seems to me, that this is some ascii stylish Symbol which I don't know how to reproduce **exactly**

Comment: To get the exact result I've added a rectangle with no fill, a white outline, fits it to the first map and resize (Position and size) it that it covers half the inner black frame. That covers the interior ticks, so I've added a new map on top and locked it with a blank canvas and added 2 grids for the ticks and the coordinates. The first map has only the 3 grid frames left. If you want you can add this information to your answer, because it is just an enhancement to your idea.